# Plotting a LineGraph in swift with unexpected error

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am new to iOS apps programming and trying to create an app that can show the score graphically every time I press a button.

```
import Charts

@IBOutlet var lineChartView: LineChartView!
```

...

```
func ChartUpdate(list1:Array<Any>) {
    var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<list1.count{
        let value = ChartDataEntry(x: list1[i] as! Double, y: list1[i] as! Double)
        lineChartEntry.append(value)
    }
    let line1 = LineChartDataSet(lineChartEntry)
    line1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    let data = LineChartData()
    data.addDataSet(line1)
    lineChartView.data = data
}
```

The purpose of writing this function is to put it into the @IBAction func so I can update the graph every time I press the button.

However I have got the following error

```
lineChartView.data = data
Use of unresolved identifier 'lineChartView'
```

How to fix it? 
I am super new to iOS programming and this platform, please do let me know if I did anything wrong. Thank you!

Comment: amke sure is conected in storyBoard, check your viewcontrolelr for the conection inspector anc check that lineChartView is conected

Comment: @kjoe Yes it is connected, the little circle on the left of the code is filled

Comment: It works fine when I put the plotting code in the main function instead of creating a new function to do the work. Don't know why the function cannot get the linechartview identifier